Warm way of saying "What are you ordering today"?
I am thinking of making an illustration as a gift for a restaurant that I frequent a lot and was thinking of a caption like "What will it be today?" (as in what are you eating today) but in that casual/warm tone.
A friend suggested '今日は何を注文しますか’ but did admit that's a little too formal/polite, and on the other extreme,'注文はなんですか' - a little too curt(?). Is there something that's kinda naturally friendly inbetween? Thanks!

Something like "今日のご注文は?" would be fine. This is friendly enough, avoids unnecessary politeness, and also suggests that the customer is a regular and familiar face. You usually need to keep ご before 注文 unless you're as close as family with the restaurant staff.
A server doesn't typically use 何 (what) when accepting orders at a restaurant. The most common phrase in this situation is ご注文をお伺いします or simply お伺いします. 注文はなんですか indeed sounds fairly curt, and even sounds like the server is angry.

Wouldn't restaurant staff use 本日 over 今日?

@istrasci 本日 sounds more formal and classy, but if this is a casual 食堂 frequented by locals, I think 今日 would be more fitting.
